# Specific order of documents Solr (or ES)

Tags: java, sql, solr, elasticsearch

Ok, my job is to create a specific order on the category page wich contains Solr results which is quite hard to realize in my opinion.

The job:

- first 2 products of the category page must be featured or most    clicks.
- further products must be chronological, BUT with a maximum of 2 products per supplier next to each other.

So:

```
 1. tv from LG (fixt)
 2. radio from Pioneer (fixt)
 3. pc monitor from Samsung (chronologic)
 4. smartphone from Samsung (chronologic)
 5. smartphone from LG (chronologic)
 6. dj set from Pioneer (chronologic)
```

So a maximum of 2 products per supplier next to each other. The category page can contain let's say 10 Samsung products, but not next to each other. ONLY of there are no products from other suppliers left, then it's ok to put them next to each other at the end of the category. So:

```
1. samsung product
2. samsung product
3. lg product
4. hp product
5. hp product
6. samsung product
7. hp product
8. hp product
9. hp product
10. hp product
11. hp product
12. hp product
13. hp product
```

As you can see. If all supplier products are finished and there is only one left (hp), just show all of them.

I was able to create this with a complex SQL function, for the homepage, where only 10 products per category are shown. But now they want to see the same order on the whole category pages as well, and those pages contain results from Solr.... So does anyone know or it's possible to create such order with Solr OR ElasticSearch?

We just got started implementing Solr, so if it's necessary to use ElasticSearch for this that would be possible as well.

EDIT:
I read this should be possible with some JAVA programming: http://sujitpal.blogspot.nl/2013/03/solr-custom-ranking-with-function.html and http://www.supermind.org/blog/756/how-to-write-a-custom-solr-functionquery Anyone ever done this before? One thing: I don't want to "boost" documents, I really want max 2 suppliers next to each other, so a truly specific order. Anyone who knows this should be possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorting or scoring is per document and not in a global context , so i dont think you can achieve this using the same.

How ever , you can use [top_hits](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html) to achieve something similar and it does work fine.

```
{
  "query": {},
  "aggs": {
    "perSupplier": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "supplier"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "TwoDocs": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 2
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I will take a look at it. Looks good. For now I was able to fix it with SQL. I thought we used Solr for the category pages, but we just used SQL queries, so it was an easy fix. But for the future we might wanna use Solr or ES for quicker results.